# How not to display the "Change languages" on Gboard

Tags: languages, gboard

I just updated Gboard and I only use two languages. However after this update, I have to press twice and choose which languages I want to swap to when obviously it's the other one...
Is it possible to only long press the space bar as before to automatically change to the other langauge? this is such a waste of time otherwise :/

Answer (score 0):

You can change languages directly from the **language switch key** (the one with the globe symbol netx the space bar). If it is not displayed, then go to `Settings > Languages & Input > Gboard > Preferences.`

From here toggle the switch for various  settings including number row and emoji and obviously language switch key. 
[image]

[image]